# How to use data of one application into other application in Android

Tags: android

i want to send input data in one application to the other application using "intent" or can we store user input from one application that can be used by other application.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set up a Content Provider: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html